# Always run a constant number of subprocesses in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, subprocess, multiprocessing

I want to use subprocesses to let 20 instances of a written script run parallel. Lets say i have a big list of urls with like 100.000 entries and my program should control that all the time 20 instances of my script are working on that list. I wanted to code it as follows:

```
urllist = [url1, url2, url3, .. , url100000]
i=0
while number_of_subproccesses < 20 and i<100000:
    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script.py', urllist[i]]
    i = i+1
```

My script just writes something into a database or textfile. It doesnt output anything and dont need more input than the url.

My problem is i wasnt able to find something how to get the number of subprocesses that are active. Im a novice programmer so every hint and suggestion is welcome. I was also wondering how i can manage it once the 20 subprocesses are loaded that the while loop checks the conditions again? I thought of maybe putting another while loop over it, something like

```
while i<100000
   while number_of_subproccesses < 20:
       subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script.py', urllist[i]]
       i = i+1
       if number_of_subprocesses == 20:
           sleep() # wait to some time until check again
```

Or maybe theres a bette possibility that the while loop is always checking on the number of subprocesses?

I also considered using the module multiprocessing, but i found it really convenient to just call the script.py with subprocessing instead of a function with multiprocessing.

Maybe someone can help me and lead me into the right direction. Thanks Alot!

Comment: related: [Limiting number of processes in multiprocessing python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23236190/4279)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking a different approach from the above - as it seems that the callback can't be sent as a parameter:

```
NextURLNo = 0
MaxProcesses = 20
MaxUrls = 100000  # Note this would be better to be len(urllist)
Processes = []

def StartNew():
   """ Start a new subprocess if there is work to do """
   global NextURLNo
   global Processes

   if NextURLNo < MaxUrls:
      proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script.py', urllist[NextURLNo], OnExit])
      print ("Started to Process %s", urllist[NextURLNo])
      NextURLNo += 1
      Processes.append(proc)

def CheckRunning():
   """ Check any running processes and start new ones if there are spare slots."""
   global Processes
   global NextURLNo

   for p in range(len(Processes):0:-1): # Check the processes in reverse order
      if Processes[p].poll() is not None: # If the process hasn't finished will return None
         del Processes[p] # Remove from list - this is why we needed reverse order

   while (len(Processes) < MaxProcesses) and (NextURLNo < MaxUrls): # More to do and some spare slots
      StartNew()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   CheckRunning() # This will start the max processes running
   while (len(Processes) > 0): # Some thing still going on.
      time.sleep(0.1) # You may wish to change the time for this
      CheckRunning()

   print ("Done!")
```

Comment: Thanks again for ur answer! Some little questions. What does len(Processes):0:-1 do and why its not sufficient to write for p in Processes: ? And i guess in the main procedure, it should be: while (len(Processes) > 0): ? Thanks for the effort again, thats a very creative answer!

Comment: `[len(Processes):0:-1]` will run through the list of processes if any in reverse order so as to avoid problems that come from deleting from a list while you are traversing it.  I'll correct the other.

Comment: There is still a little problem with Processes[p].poll() it says that "list indices must be integers, not popen". So is it possible to get the index of our p in the Processes list? Maybe something like Processes.index(p)?

Comment: If i extend the if Processes[p].poll() with == 0, everything works fine! Thank you very much again!

Comment: This is great! I also had to change processes[p].poll() to processes[p].poll() == 0 and for the reverse range I just used reversed(range(len(processes))). Thank you!

Comment: Warning: Some processes will return values other than zero if they finished but had a problem, (some actually return non-zero for success as well), so we need to check for the poll returning something other than `None` to detect if they have finished.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep count as you start them and use a callback from each subprocess to start a new one if there are any url list entries to process.

e.g. Assuming that your sub-process calls the OnExit method passed to it as it ends:

```
NextURLNo = 0
MaxProcesses = 20
NoSubProcess = 0
MaxUrls = 100000

def StartNew():
   """ Start a new subprocess if there is work to do """
   global NextURLNo
   global NoSubProcess

   if NextURLNo < MaxUrls:
      subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script.py', urllist[NextURLNo], OnExit])
      print "Started to Process", urllist[NextURLNo]
      NextURLNo += 1
      NoSubProcess += 1

def OnExit():
   NoSubProcess -= 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
   for n in range(MaxProcesses):
      StartNew()
   while (NoSubProcess > 0):
      time.sleep(1)
      if (NextURLNo < MaxUrls):
         for n in range(NoSubProcess,MaxProcesses):
             StartNew()
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much, for that complete solution for my question. that is helping me alot! The callback idea is really nice and handy. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: A little question again: I tried out your code but somehow its giving me a Typerror: argument of type 'function' is not iterable, in the subprocess.Popen line. I know it has something to do with calling the OnExit function, but what does it mean and how can i prevent this? Maybe for information im using Python3.3 on Windows7.

Comment: Oh i think i got it, i have to implement to run the passed OnExit in my  script.py. Right?

Comment: It seems that its not possible to pass a function in the argument list, or am i wrong? Is there some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 2):

To keep constant number of concurrent requests, you could use a thread pool:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def process_url(url):
    # ... handle a single url

urllist = [url1, url2, url3, .. , url100000]
for _ in Pool(20).imap_unordered(process_url, urllist):
    pass
```

To run processes instead of threads, remove `.dummy` from the import.