# Limiting number of processes in multiprocessing python

Tags: python, urllib2

My requirement is to generate `hundreds of HTTP POST requests per second`. I am doing it using `urllib2`.

```
def send():
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_data(data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

while datetime.datetime.now() <= ftime:
    p=Process(target=send, args=[])
    p.start()
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

The problem is this code `sometimes for some iterations` throws either of following exceptions:

```
HTTP 503 Service Unavailable.
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

I have tried using `requests(HTTP for humans)` as well but I am having some proxy issues with that module. Seems like `requests` is sending http packets to proxy server even when target machine is within same LAN. I don't want packets to go to proxy server.

Comment: If the goal is to generate a ton of requests I wouldn't start those in individual processes like that. Very inefficient. Use something like twisted and an epoll based reactor: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html

Comment: @agrinh Thanks for reply. you have any idea on how to use Twisted in loop, I could generate only single request using it. Can you please provide some code snippet.

Comment: [Problem with multi threaded Python app and socket connections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4783735/4279) has code examples that show how make multiple connections using various frameworks e.g., `asyncio`, `twisted`, `gevent`.

Comment: You can use Pool workers for multiprocessing, check the "16.6.1.5. Using a pool of workers" title in https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to limit number of concurrent connections is to use a thread pool:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import izip, repeat
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads for I/O bound tasks
from urllib2 import urlopen

def fetch(url_data):
    try:
        return url_data[0], urlopen(*url_data).read(), None
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        return url_data[0], None, str(e)

if __name__=="__main__":
    pool = Pool(20) # use 20 concurrent connections
    params = izip(urls, repeat(data)) # use the same data for all urls
    for url, content, error in pool.imap_unorderred(fetch, params):
        if error is None:
           print("done: %s: %d" % (url, len(content)))
        else:
           print("error: %s: %s" % (url, error))
```

`503 Service Unavailable` is a server error. It might fail to handle the load.

`Name or service not known` is a dns error. If you need make many requests; install/enable a local caching dns server.