# Simplest way to do multi-threading/parallel processing in Python

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

I have a list of files that need to be preprocessed using just one command before being mosaicked together. This preprocessing command uses third-party software via system call to write to a geoTIFF. I wanted to use multi-threading so that the individual files can be pre-processed at the same time and then, once all individual files are processed, the results can be mosaicked together.

I have never used multi-threading/parallel processing before, and after hours of searching on the internet, I still have no clue what the best, simplest way to go about this is.

Basically, something like this:

```
files_list = # list of .tif files that need to be mosaicked together but first, need to be individually pre-processed

for tif_file in files_list:
    # kick the pre-processing step out to the system, but don't wait for it to finish before moving to preprocess the next tif_file

# wait for all tiffs in files_list to finish pre-processing
# then mosaick together
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What is the output of the pre-processing?

Comment: Any reason this task should be parallelized? Doing these files one after another would be definetely much faster (except few special cases) due to overhead python has for multithreading.

Comment: @PeterWood the output of the pre-processing step are geoTIFFs that I need to mosaic together

Comment: Are geoTIFFs files or in memory?

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota Well, the purpose was to make the code faster, hah. Can you explain in more detail? How do you know that that is the case? Thx

Comment: @PeterWood They are actual files

Comment: Well there are many detailed answers to this already on SO. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10789458/6313992 . In short, if you are just doing python operations you are much better jusing doing them in main porgram. Special cases include: obtaining responses over http/sockets, writing to files, any blocking io... In detail explanation: https://42bits.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/python-global-interpreter-lock-gil-explained-pycon-tech-talk/

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota Thank you. I should have clarified but I'm actually using a system call to do the preprocessing, it's not a command that is native to Python. And yes the preprocessing step writes files using a third-party software that has a multi-threading option. I just didn't know how to wait for that step to be complete for all input files before moving on.

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota I edited my question to add more details about this

Answer (score 0):

See the [**`multiprocessing`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) documentation.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    pool.map(pre_processing_command, files_list)

    mosaic()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use multiple processor cores you should use [multiprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), in the most simple case you can use something like:

```
def process_function(tif_file):
    ... your processing code here ...

for tif_file in files_list:
    p = Process(target=process_function, args=(tif_file))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

You need to take care, because so many process running at same time can overpass the PC resources, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123325/always-run-a-constant-number-of-subprocesses-in-parallel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610075/limiting-the-number-of-processes-running-at-a-time-from-a-python-script) for solutions to the problem.

You can also use [threading.thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html?highlight=threading.thread#threading.Thread), but it uses only one processor core, and is restricted by the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock)